# TypeScript in PhpStorm - no autocomplete

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I just started with TypeScript & React, my test app works but I cannot get autocomplete for any `window` or `document` function, any idea why?

`document.getElementById` - `Unresolved variable or type document` etc.

I am compiling through Babel in webpack and do not have `.tsconfig.json` file.

I also installed `@types/react-dom` but `ReactDOM.render` is still complaining in editor: `Unresolved function or method render()`

This is not normal right? Thank you.

Comment: it's not normal. Do you have **HTML** predefined library enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**? also, what file type is the `*.d.ts` pattern assigned to in **Settings | Editor | File Types**?

Comment: Hi. I have checked `HTML` and `NodeJs core`. I cant find this extension but there is a .ts icon on it.

Comment: Seems like phpstorm bug, when i turn on TypeScript language service autocomplete for window etc works, but is is showing error that jsx is not enabled even when i create tsconfig file with `"jsx": "react"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like it was a bug, it disappeared after few days, i am not aware of a update though, weird but solved, thanks.